# Question should be closed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounty

I think [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239232/meaning-and-origin-of-word-pantheon/239549#239549) should be closed as off-topic for take-your-pick: unclear what's being asked, too broad, basic (dictionaries for use examples), and better for ELL if it were . . . better.

But it has an open bounty currently. So can or should anything be done? Thanks for any attention to this vitally urgent crisis. o.o

Comment: I don't have rep to vote to close. I tried to flag as unclear but got a message saying no go because it has a bounty.

Comment: You are right. My mistake.

Comment: It's a bad, run-of-the-mill, read-the-dictionary-for-me question. But it will have no lasting impact, and will be carried away by the river of history. In other words, it's a problem, but a temporary problem. Don't sweat it. I did appreciate your invitation and encouragement to Krishna to come join ELL. I think he'd find many fellow-travellers there.

Comment: Ah, I was not really that serious about it, @Dan. Maybe just because I took the time to read everything and to try to answer. I got just frustrated enough to want to he Krishna know that the question is confusing, and maybe to call attention to the basic issues in case anyone spends time and effort trying to figure out what is wanted.

Comment: @JimReynolds - I can understand your frustration. I admit OP was a bit pedantic and the question could be better arranged. Nonetheless I think is has its merits in calling attention to the origin and use of an uncommon term. I changed my comment into a full answer hoping to give once and  for all what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Josh61 I appreciate all the work you put into that answer; it is thorough and well-presented. On the other hand, I *don't* like EL&U to provide answers already available in dictionaries and other general references. *Especially* good answers. I think it just encourages more of the same (i.e. unadulterated parasitism). When users see people getting free handouts they will *ask for more handouts*. But hey, maybe that's just because my parents would literally *never* tell me what a word meant: the *only* response they ever gave was "Look it up." :)

Comment: @DanBron - how can I disagree with you! In this specific case I think OP was looking for some extra  support  regarding the meaning an usage of the term for the fact it is quite uncommon and refers to Greek mythology. Having said that the issue you raise may well apply to the majority of questions (and the are a lot in this site)  which ask for the etymology of words and expressions. Some are  easy others require more research., but they are almost all GR at the end of the day ..where should we draw the line?

Comment: Sometimes fuzzy lines make the world go 'round. Or is that itself actually a wobbly ellipse. If @Josh61 is interested in supplying a good answer, I suppose it will be useful.

Comment: @Josh61 A very cogent point. To me, the line is drawn by *how much personal effort and research the OP has demonstrated*. In fact, this is where my first, emotional, reaction will almost always stem from, and following on that my position on whether it deserves an answer. In this case, Krishna demonstrated essentially *zero* effort; he hadn't even checked a dictionary! In fact, when you *quoted* the general reference at him, he said thy if cleared up his confusion considerably. And now the fact he's added a bounty makes it feel like he's trying to *pay someone to understand the word for him*.

Comment: At the other end of the "*what does this word mean*" spectrum, where the OP demonstrated an *inspiring* amount of prior research, you have the [ZOMG question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/what-is-the-origin-of-zomg). Or a couple of [your recent questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229365/on-the-origin-and-usage-of-mainstream). Or any of [Mari-Lou's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238004/where-on-earth-is-penguin-from).

Answer (score 1):

Get with the program - it's democracy in action.

Several times over the years I've been annoyed by bounties which prevent me from closevoting, but in the end there will only be one of two possibilities...

> 1: Wait until the bounty ends, *then* cast your closevote, and hope 4 other users will back you up (I seriously doubt any mod would wade in with a unilateral VTC in such circumstances).
>
> 2: Accept that in any "user-controlled" site, you won't *always* agree with everyone else.

I started off leaning towards option #1 every time, but #2 is just *easier*.

Comment: Now that close votes which expire can be recast, you can have a second go at getting 4 more people to agree with you. And a third, and a fourth! So much fun.

Comment: In a complete surprise ending, the guy who asked a completely unresearched question and wasn't willing to put any personal effort into learning, even when spoon-fed by many friendly and high rep users here, has abandoned his question. The bounty was auto-rewarded. I have voted to close.